# c++ async: What happens to std::shared_future memory allocation if I don't call get()?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, allocation

I am working on a simple idea and I came across this problem. What happens if after an async call as shown below the program exits without calling shared_future.get()?
Will I have a memory leak?

```
//async function
std::shared_future<double*> sharedFutures = std::async(std::launch::async, myAsyncFunc, argument1, argument2);

if (   realtimeCondition )
{
    //what happens to sharedFutures memory allocation after exiting
    //memory leak?
    return 0;
}

//getting results
for (sharedFuture : sharedFutures )
   double* res = sharedFuture.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: its destructor is called https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future/%7Eshared_future

Comment: `If *this is the last object referring to the shared state, destroys the shared state. Otherwise does nothing.`

Comment: why do you think calling `get` or not calling `get`  would make a difference? I mean there is no problem with calling `get` twice, so if your misunderstanding was the `get` would release the resources, that was wrong, resources are released in destructors

Comment: I suggest to read about RAII, its a fundamental principle in C++ and the reason why knowing exactly when a destructor is called is so great.

Comment: hence, shared_future destructors are called when exiting  and not when having collected the futures via get()?

Comment: It destructor gets called and synchronizes with the end of the async task. This last thing is a very useful property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shared_future` to some extend mimics `std::shared_ptr`. They both manage a shared resource. The resource is released when the last `shared_x` is destroyed. This is checked in the destructor (cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future/%7Eshared_future):

> ~shared_future();  (since C++11)
>
> If `*this` is the last object referring to the shared state, destroys the shared state. Otherwise does nothing.

If a class manages a resource it should release it in the destructor. Thats true for all classes. The difference here is that the same resource is shared between potentially many objects. So each object has to check if it is the last one to own the resource before it can destroy it.

> hence, shared_future destructors are called when exiting and not when having collected the futures via get()?

It would be bad and weird if an object suddenly destroys itself when you call one of its methods. Here specifically, both `shared_future` and `shared_ptr` would be practically useless when everytime you access the object they manage that object gets destroyed. The `shared_future` in your example gets destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, now it's much more clear to me. I will also check out the RAII

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly calling get() on future will change state->retrieved of future to true but not calls destruction. Destruction of future of any type doesn't depend on its own state.

Comment: yes, that was my initial guess, but it was wrong.